# Making a selector the inner html of a link

Tags: jquery

I have a large PHP generated table of users from a database. Each username has a link and I'm trying to make it where if you click that link, the link hides and a text box becomes visible so that you can change the username. Each textbox has an id that matches to the link caption. When I test var x in an alert, it shows up exactly how it's supposed to, ex: '#username'. When I plug x into the selector of the show() function, however, it doesn't work.

I know that code looks somewhat confusing but really all I'm trying to do is pass $this.html() to a selector for use in the .show() function.

```
            $(".userLink").each(function (){
                $(this).click(function(){
                    $(this).hide();
                    var x = ("'#"+$(this).html()+"'");
                    (x).show();
                    return false;
                });
            });
```

Comment: Is user name can contain spaces and other non alphabetical symbols? In this case selector of text box will be not valid. It's better to work for example with `UserId`.

Comment: nope, usernames are one word and cannot contain spaces/symbols

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need the quotes in the selector string.

```
$(".userLink").click(function(){
  $(this).hide();
  var x = "#"+$(this).text();
  // alert(x); // should be #username (without quotes)
  $(x).show();
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it to

```
var x = $("'#"+$(this).html()+"'");
    x.show();
```

You were missing the `$` in front of the parens.

Or you can use

```
var x = "'#"+$(this).html()+"'";
$(x).show();
```

Either way will work, you were just missing a `$` where needed so it wasn't being grabbed by jQuery.

**Edit**

I think the other issue is you are using the `html` rather than the `text` from the link

```
var x = "'#"+$(this).text()+"'";
$(x).show();
```

I assume what you are trying to do is grab the text not all of the html, because you wouldnt have an element with the ID `<div id='<a href="#">linky</a>'></div>`

Comment: Hmm sounds like theres a bit more going on, because your page shouldn't be going anywhere with the return false. Are you sure  `.userLink` is the name of the class for each link?

Comment: Yep, each link is userLink. When I comment out the var x/s.show() stuff and switch it with an alert, that works fine for each link and it stays on the page.

Comment: @TimH Edited my answer, might want to try `text()` rather than `html()`

Comment: Didn't work w/ text(). I've used alerts to test everything, including .html(), and it all seems perfectly set... don't know what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".userLink").click(function (){
    $(this).hide();
    var x = $("'#"+$(this).html()+"'");
    x.show();
    return false;
});
```